# database design concept

Tags: database, database-design

I need advise wish scenario is most efficient to represent my data

### Table (A) fields:

ID (key), width (number), Height (number)

### Table (B) fields:

ID (key), description (string), price (number)

Table (A) that have most of the basic data but one record from this table can have multi records from table (B)

For example: record A2 can have B1, B2 while record A3 can have B2, B3, B4

Now should I use master / detail 1 to many relation ? in this case the user will repeat entering the same "description" field from Table (B) for each similar value

or I should create a third table (AB) to hold the related data from both A and B ?

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at the cart platforms how they arrange it. OpenCart for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> in this case the user will repeat entering the same "description" field from Table (B) for each similar value

I don't know what you mean by this but to me it looks like a typical many to many relation (A2 has B1, B2 and B2 has A2, A3). In that case, I would suggest creating the third "(AB)" table.

Comment: hi, what I meant is if I did not use third table and used "1 to many" relation the user when entering values for description field in B2 he will write the same description again and again as in real world it will not be only 2 records but many more. so I go with the third table ?